# How to get row with two time column in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have a table like this where I have classified two time Morning and Evening.

[image]

I want to retrieve row with input such as current time. For example,

```
SELECT name 
FROM TimeMaster 
WHERE  start_at < '02:00:00' AND end_at > '02:00:00';
```

I am getting Morning row, but if I give other input I am not getting any rows.

But if I give other input such as..

```
SELECT name 
FROM TimeMaster 
WHERE start_at < '17:28:00' AND end_at > '17:28:00';
```

No rows are retrieved.

Comment: Please edit the question to add these details

Comment: You _should_ only be getting the morning row, because that row is the only one which matches.

Comment: I am getting Morning rows for any input that belong to Morning time..but unable to get Evening time for any evening time according to my table

Comment: @BhhavyaPatel No answer will work. If there are just two rows (for morning and evening); it is better to code this logic, rather than using a separate table. Use midnight time for bounds checking

Comment: I have changed evening time from 14:00:01 to 23:59:59...it is working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**USE:**

```
SELECT name FROM TimeMaster WHERE  xinputime between start_at and end_at;
```

where `xinputime`  is your given random time which can be the current time or something you desire. And also change `start_at` time from `00:00:00` to `11:59:59` and `end_at` time from `12:00:00 to 23:59:59`

Comment: I am getting Morning rows for any input that belong to Morning time..but unable to get Evening time for any evening time according to my table

Comment: you have used wrong operator. use <symbol for start at and > for end at

Comment: and the time span you have taken looks inappropriate because stander time span is 00:00:00 from 11:59:59 and 12:00:00 from 23:59:59 if you can replace the time span with this. Then it will be easy for you to work.

Comment: Yes..I have just changed it and it is working perfectly